# Django Models create product bundle

Tags: django, django-models, e-commerce, python-decorators

I have a products model

```
class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
weight= models.PositiveIntegerField(default=454)
brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_brand", blank=True, default=1)
flavour = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
discription = models.TextField(default='')
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

@property
def imageURL(self):
    try:
        url = self.image.url
    except:
        url = ''
    return url
```

Now I want to be able to create a bundle of let's say, buy 5 items for £ 10.  In the shopping cart, it will be added as a 5 X Multibuy.  So I have another model called Multibuy

```
class Multibuy(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Multibuy')
brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="multibuy_brand", blank=True, default=1)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product,  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
max_items = models.IntegerField(default=8, null=True, blank=True)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

I am curious to know if there is a better way to do this.  For example, write a decorator in the products model, and do away with the Multibuy model.
Bearing in mind that the price and the quantity of the bundles for different products will be different and the admin needs to add that and may want to alter it later.

Comment: Do you need another model tho ? 
You could write a function that return a discounted price based on how many products the client has in his cart. 
What you call a bundle is a client buying many products at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, the bundle is essentially buying multiple items of the same product.  What would be the best way to invoke that function from the front end i.e by clicking on a button for multibuy option.  Will I create a new view for multibuy and a seperate URL ?